# Why is it mandatory to have a child method in Parent class to call it with a reference of parent class which is referring to an object of child class?

Tags: java

```
public class A
{  }

public class B extends A
{
  public void add()
  {
   System.out.println("add in B");
  }
}
```

Now here if we call add in following way hen it gives an error:
A a1 = new B;
a1.add();

But when we add the add() method in class A and then call in the similar fashion then add() method of child class is called.

i.e.

```
public class A
{
  public void add()
  {
   System.out.println("add in A");
  }
}

public class B extends A
{
  public void add()
  {
   System.out.println("add in B");
  }
}
```

call:

```
A a1 = new B;
a1.add();
```

output:

> add in B

Why is it so?

Comment: This is the case of Polymorphism

Answer (score 2):

at the method invocation of a1.add() the compiler checks if the method is present. But it only knows that a1 is a reference to an object of class A, which does not have that method. So the compilation fails.

In this trivial example it would probably be easy for the compiler to deduct the correct type. But in more general cases it wouldn't. And therefore this kind of logic is not part of the specs.

Comment: And when actually calling the method, JVM resolves runtime, which exact method to call based on runtime type of the value held in the variable. In your case, the real value of variable a1 is B, so method add declared in class B is called.

Answer (score 1):

Because java does not know at compile time that a1 will refer to an instance of B at runtime. It only knows the declared type, so it only allows calls that work with the declared type.

Answer (score 0):

When the Java compiler looks at the reference `a1`, it knows what methods are available.  In your first example, class `A` does not have `add()` in its API.  It is legal in this case to perform a cast of `a1` to `B` like so:

((B)a1).add();

and the compiler will not complain.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call a method on an object of declared type A but implement it only in a subclass B of A.
In this situation you would normally make A an [abstract class](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) and declare add() an abstract method in A.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers...I had a doubt too regarding this but now I am clear :)
And one more thing ..you don't have to go into the trouble of declaring an abstract method,just make an empty method with the same name and signature in your parent class and    " voila " all compilation errors are gone ;)

In your case you can add a void add(){} method like this and you wont have any problems